# What is the formula for the Tesla Finance calculation?

Tags: calculation, auto-loan

According to http://www.teslamotors.com/true-cost-of-ownership with the fields set to a rate of 3.3%, down payment 10% over a 72 month term, it calculates this to be $980/mo.

How did they get there? I'm not getting that number if I just crunch the numbers manually, are they including other factors in the calculation?

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-a-Loan-Payment)

The formula is M = P * ( J / (1 - (1 + J)^ -N)).

M: monthly payment **RESULT = 980.441...**

P: principal or amount of loan **63963 (71070 - 10% down * 71070)**

J: monthly interest; annual interest divided by 100, then divided by 12. **.00275 (3.3% / 12)**

N: number of months of amortization, determined by length in years of loan. **72 months**

See [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_calculator#The_formula) for the derivation of the formula

Comment: If you have excel you can plug this formula in `=PMT(0.033/12,72,71070*0.9)`. First parameter is the rate, second is the number of payments and the last one is the amount.